# Does creating a svn tag for old code at present causes any trouble?

Tags: svn

Hi I have a old svn code which wasn't committed earlier in past. And now if I put a svn tag with

```
svn copy
```

without committing the actual files to current code, will that cause any trouble to current code? I guess no. But I am afraid as we have a large set of files in repository. Let me know if I am correct!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you commit your old code to the copy/tag rather than to the trunk (assuming your latest code is in your trunk) then the trunk is not touched and your old code does not interfere with the latest code.